# In Flutter Firebase Storage Get reference by Url and delete Gives 'Location Cannot be Null Error' in phones running in older Android versions

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I have this function written to delete images stored in my firebase storage, which works fine with the emulator running Android 10. But when I tried to the same function in an emulator running API 22(Android 5.1) it gives me this error and the delete does not work. And my apps min sdk version is set as API 21(Android 5).

```
  Future deleteImageData(String imageData) async {
    FirebaseStorage.instance
        .getReferenceFromUrl(imageData)
        .then((reference) => reference.delete())
        .catchError((e) => print(e));
  }
```

This is the imageData I am passing to this function
[image: This is the imageData I am passing to this function]

So this will fetch the reference to the image stored in the Firebase Storage and delete it.

This is the error I get when debugging
[image: This is the error I get when debugging]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to include: 1) the exact error message (copy/paste). 2) the code that calls `deleteImageData`, specifically how `imageUrl` is populated. 3) Add a `print(imageUrl)` in `deleteImageData` to see the value you get, and include both the updated code and its output in the question.

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Also today I found the solution I have forgotten to add the await in front of the statement fixed this.